# remote command via ssh: returned heading spaces skipped

Tags: ssh

For a simple example:

```
ssh user@ip echo "    messages"
```

this output like:

```
messages
```

not the expected(with heading spaces):

```
    messages
```

and the heading spaces are skipped, how to keep these spaces within the returned output?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `ssh` accepts only single `command` argument. If you pass more than one, all of them are [passed through `bash -c "command"`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/session.c#L1903), which basically removes all the additional spaces from additional arguments. Workaround can be

```
ssh user@ip 'echo "    messages"'
```